# HTTP Code in Java Exceptions

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, exception

In a layered application, I have to define the HTTP Code of an exception using Spring Annotation @ResponseStatus.

For example:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Illegal argument")
public class IllegalContentException{


}
```

It works, but I would like to know if this is a bad practice when trying to avoid breaking Single Responsiblity Pattern (in this approach the exception knows about HTTP Codes).

The question is:

- Should HTTP Code be defined in exceptions without taking in count the layer they belong to? Should HTTP Code be defined in exceptions belonging to DAO, Service layer and/or Controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to put the response codes in each exception, one option is to create a centralized exception handler with a `@ControllerAdvice` class consisting of methods with `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ResponseStatus` annotations.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CentralizedExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalContentException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleError(IllegalContentException e) {
        return "Illegal argument";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this kind of approach, better than specifying HTTP settings in each exception. I didn't know about  ControllerAdvice annotation, will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I belive the answer can be found at the beginning on https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.

Copy&paste from the provided website:
"Goal is to not handle exceptions explicitly in Controller methods where possible. They are a cross-cutting concern better handled separately in dedicated code.

There are three options: per exception, per controller or globally."

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. Indeed there are three options, but I wonder which of them is a best practice. Taking it as a cross-cutting concern sounds like a point, but giving more than one Responsibility to each Exception is one also.